# oracle can not connect to system user as sysdba?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am facing weird problem when trying to connect to the system user using sqlplus (running as administrator) as below:

```
conn system/system@JDT as sysdba
```

But I get message that says:

> ERROR:ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

When I connect as below, it is connecting normally

```
conn system/system@JDT
```

I tried to access the same user using toad as sysdba and normal, and I can connect with no problems... Why am I just not able to connect to `system` user as `sysdba` only through sqlplus?!

Answer (score 2):

I don't get why you would want to give any other user sysdba privileges. SYS and SYSTEM have different functions in oracle.  However, if you really have to, then you can do:

```
grant sysdba to system
```

and then you should be able to connect.

We normally connect SYS as SYSDBA or / as SYSDBA (with OS authentication) but only when we have to.

Comment: Where/how do you call this command? I'm getting this error `ORA-65175: cannot grant SYSDBA privilege locally in the root`

Answer (score 0):

When you execute conn system/password as sysdba, Oracle won't even check the user and password

Check http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dba006.htm#ADMIN11046

Comment: Please can you be more specific ... i can not get it

Comment: If you have the SYSDBA privilege, you can connect to the database by specifying CONNECT AS SYSDBA.

Comment: but I readly can access same user with same privilege using toad ?

Comment: Yes,  Toad does the Connection with username and password and then checks the Role and previleges.